# Redis call callback with QUEUED as value of argument

Tags: node.js, redis

i'm testing a module with mocha, and the scenario is a small class which has methods, with an required callback argument.

When i run the test on the first `describe` it gets the expected result, when it runs on the second and third `describe` , `beforeEach` and `afterEach` the class actually creates a new redis clients and calls `end()` when it supposed to end.

```
client.hget('profile:1','name',function(error,profileID){ /* <= profileID value is QUEUED */
 console.log(profileID); //<= QUEUED 
 });
```

Why the callback is getting `QUEUED` as value for its arguments? it doesn't throw any errors..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding

```
if (error) console.log(error);
```

or better yet for for debugging:

```
client.hget('profile:1','name',redis.print);
```

Redis won't throw exceptions that kill the process as far as I have exprinced unless you tell it to.

It depends on your code but you may want to wait for the `connect` or `idle` event

something like:

```
client.on("idle",function(){
//Your code here 
});
```

Comment: still no change, it just results to the same thing. Maybe i should rewrite some stuff before i try again.

Answer (score 0):

as it seems, it needed a lot of debugging to finally found, that the script it created redis clients, closed them, and tried to send a command, but the client had already closed. Also some minor syntax erros at redis commands in multi array arguments (hard to spot)